# Bedeutung der Redewendung "Zeit(en) erfassen"

Tags: meaning

Ich bin auf den Satz

> Zum Erfassen und Dokumentieren aller Zeiten ist diese App am besten

gestoßen, aber konnte die Bedeutung von *Zeit(en) erfassen* nicht begreifen.

Comment: In welchem Kontext bitte? _Die Zeit erfassen_ ist zum Beispiel üblich für _die **Arbeitszeit** erfassen (aufschreiben, stempeln)_.

Comment: Jetzt ist es klar, der Satz, der ich gelesen habe : zum Erfassen und Dokumentieren aller Zeiten ist diese App am besten

Comment: @Marwan Ich habe deine Frage bearbeitet und den Kontext ergänzt. Falls ich deine Intention nicht richtig wiedergegeben haben sollte, zögere bitte nicht, die Änderungen zurückzusetzen und die Frage anders zu stellen.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Danke, das war super

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obwohl in der Frage der Kontext fehlt, ist es ziemlich klar, dass es um die Erfassung von Arbeitzeiten zum Zweck der Kostenverrechnung (an Kunden oder unternehmensintern) geht. Eine Google-Suche nach dem Stichwort "Zeiterfassung" lohnt sich.